# How to write into div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a for example content variable in javascript which will have a html tags inside with certain values.
How can I put that in the div when button is pressed.

For example :

This is a content which I want to use:

```
var contentString = '<div id="info">'+
'<h2><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Info:</b></h2>'+
'<div id="bodyContent">'+ 
'<div style=width:220px;display:inline-block;>'+
'<p>&nbsp; Name: '+ this.name + '</p>' +
'<p>&nbsp; Last name: '+ this.last+ '</p>' +
'<p>&nbsp; 
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</form>';
```

And I want to put it into : `<div id=something"></div>`
In javascript I can have something like:

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
// What to put in here?
});
```

Comment: Please take note that all answers thus far suggest calling the .html property which is like doing .innerHTML . I suggest you don't write HTML directly but rather use appendChild and createElement instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I put that in the div when button is pressed.

Like this:

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
  $('#something').html(contentString);
});
```

More info about `html()`;

- http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not misunderstanding, then this will work:

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
    $('#something').html(contentString);
});
```

This does, of course, assume that you have an element with an `id` of `button` (though I assume you do, otherwise you wouldn't have put that jQuery).

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hAEYT/).

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Answer (score 2):

It goes like this:

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
   $("#something").html(contentString);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should fix up your markup. You have unbalanced elements, and you can't have new lines in the string without escaping it. Try this instead:

```
var contentString = '<div id="info">'+
'<h2><b style="text-indent: 40px">Info:</b></h2>'+
'<div id="bodyContent">'+ 
'<div style="width:220px;display:inline-block;">'+
'<p style="text-indent: 1em">Name: '+ this.name + '</p>' +
'<p style="text-indent: 1em">Last name: '+ this.last+ '</p>' +
'</div>';
```

Note that I skipped the `&nbsp;` and replaced them with style attributes. You really should put these styles in a stylesheet, though.

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
 $('#something').html(contentString);
});
```

Keep in mind that the variables in contentString will not be evaluated when the click event on the button fires, meaning that this.name and this.last will not change. Do you need to update these values on click as well?